# Need help understanding why $f^{-1}$ is not continuous in this examples from Munkres' Topology.

Tags: general-topology

The author writes that the map $f:[0, 1) \to S^{1}$, where $S^1$ is given the subspace topology from $\mathbb{R^2}$, given by $t \mapsto(cos(2\pi t), sin(2\pi t))$ is such that $f^{-1}$ is not continuous.

The explanation that is given is that $f([0,1/4))$ is not open in $S^1$ because the point $p = f(0)$ lies in no open set $V$ of $\mathbb{R^2}$ such that $V\cap S^1 \subset f([0, 1/4))$.

I don't see how we know that there is no $V$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f([0,\tfrac{1}{4}))$ is the quarter-circle of $S^1$ lying in the first quadrant, with the point $(0,1)$ removed. Now $p = (1,0)$. Any neighborhood $N$ of $p$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ contains points in the quarter circle of $S^1$ lying in the fourth quadrant. These points are not in $f([0,\tfrac{1}{4}))$, thus
$$N \cap S^1 \not\subset f([0,\tfrac{1}{4})).$$
Therefore $f([0,\tfrac{1}{4}))$ is not open in $S^1$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $U$ is an open ball centered at $f(0)=(1,0)$ and $(x,y)\in U\cap S^1$, show that $(x,-y)\in U\cap S^1$

Now, if there is a $V$, then there is a $V$ which is an open ball around $f(0)=(1,0)$.

Comment: $(x,y)\in U\cap S^1$ does not imply $(x,-y)\in U$ necessarily.

Comment: If $U$ is an open ball centered at $(1,0)$ it is true, but I guess I didn't say "centered," using the vaguer "around." Edited. @Omarkhayyam